# BackboneJS not giving the output

Tags: backbone.js

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>BackboneJs</title>
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Accounts Manager</h1>
<hr />
<div class="page"></div>
</div>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore- min.js">   
</script> 
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js">       
</script>

<script>
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {

        '': "home"
    }

});

var router = new Router();
router.on('route: home', function(){
    console.log("We have loaded the home page");
});

Backbone.history.start();  

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Everything here seems to be place and the console log should give the output in console but the heading is coming fine on the page but output in the console is missing with no error.!

Comment: hey did the answer fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to remove the space before home when listening to the router

```
var router = new Router();
router.on('route:home', function(){
    console.log("We have loaded the home page");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rHZWc/